# Deleting viruses from USB

Tags: usb-drive, malware

When I use my USB drive on Windows computers, then return to my Linux computer, I find many extra files are added to the drive, often `exe` files and various folders.

- Is it sufficient to delete the new files? Will some viruses be placed inside my files?
- Is there some software to help identify and delete these, from Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also the possibility, that any malware install itself in the [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)/[VBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_boot_record) boot sectors of the drive. From there it could be executed automatically if booting from USB storage devices is enabled.

As soon as the malware runs, it could install nasty [root/bootkits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit).

To clean the MBR of the usb drive from any malware, [install a new one](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/install-a-new-mbr-to-your-usb-flash-device/). 
And remove any existing *bootflag* from all partitions on the drive by using `fdisk` or any other partition manager (gparted, cfdisk, ...)

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, unless a virus appends itself to an `exe` file.
2. Try [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/), an open-source virus scanner which runs on Linux.

Comment: Appending code to existing executables is an incredibly common technique. Just search for "virus append exe", there's gobs of them out there to eat you.

Comment: That's quite interesting... editing my post to reflect it.